I cannot transfer learning YAMNET for multi-label problem
I'm using this tutorial to apply transfer learning to my dataset which has 32 classes of audio.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/transfer_learning_audio?hl=en
But this does not seem to work for multi label data.
Is this all meant to be a single-label classifier?
The tutorial uses SparseCategoricalCrossentropy with a single number for each file.
In my case, when using multi-label it would have more than one number for some files, for example:
[2, 4, 3, [2,4], [3,5], 5, 2]

and I get the error:

ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.

Then I change to BinaryCrossEntropy and one-hot encode, but it also fails. Has anyone managed to to multi-label using YAMNET? Thank you.
